# JBOSS 6: [CachedConnectionManager] Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I am getting an exception every time a transaction gets over in JBOSS 6. I understand that I am not closing the connection manually, but I want to avoid it by changing the logger mode. For achieving this I added the following lines

```
<logger category="org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager">
      <level name="FATAL"/>
   </logger>
```

in **jboss-logging.xml**  under  jboss-6.1.0_Final/server/default/deploy. 
The problem is it's not reflecting on the console. The root logger is in INFO mode.
 The exact stack trace is

```
INFO  [CachedConnectionManager] Closing a connection for you.  Please close them yourself: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@d0249e: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager.registerConnection(CachedConnectionManager.java:278) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:524) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92) [:3.6.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) [:3.6.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) [:3.6.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74) [:3.6.6.Final]
```

I would appreciate if anyone can let me know documentation on jboss-logging.xml . We have migrated from Jobss 4 which had jog4j.xml under conf dir . Are both these files are similar  ?

Comment: Have you had some good news on this issue? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> track-statements : This boolean element specifies whether to check for
>   unclosed statements when a connection is returned to the pool. If
>   true, a warning message is issued for each unclosed statement. If the
>   log4j category **org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection**
>   has trace level enabled, a stack trace of the connection close call is
>   logged as well. This is a debug feature that can be turned off in
>   production.

source: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/beta500/html/ch13s13.html

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow below steps below in Jboss 6.1 to solve this issue,
01:15:19,406 INFO [CachedConnectionManager] Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection@ef028b

java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE

at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager.register

I disable JBoss CachedConnectionManager to fix issues.

**Step 1:** $JBOSS_HOME/server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar/server.xml

Comment or delete the className CachedConnectionValue:

```
<!--Valve className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve"

                cachedConnectionManagerObjectName="jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager"

                transactionManagerObjectName="jboss:service=TransactionManager" /-->
```

**Step 2:** server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml

Comment or delete CachedConnectionManager:

```
<!--

      <depends>jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager</depends>

-->
```

**Step 3:** $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/standardjboss.xml

Comment or delete all CachedConnectionInterceptor statements:

```
<!--

    <interceptor>org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor</interceptor>

-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Messages related to `Closing a result set you left open! Please close it yourself` in the server.log file mean that track-statements is enabled and ResultSet/Statements are not being closed. This tracking is enabled by the following option on the data source

Resolution:
If you are `mssql-ds.xml` in EAP

use `<track-statements>false</track-statements>`

Please refer the same from
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/40841