# Although CMT, " Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself:"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA, Hibernate, Jboss and container managed transactions. When I am trying to save my big entity with data , it throws following exceptions. Think my entity as a graph model. This exceptions is not thrown every time.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor] (WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:53478])         javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Unexpected Error
2014-11-07 13:40:06,332 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager] (WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:53478]) Closing a connection for you.  Please close them yourself: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@1261dfa: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager.registerConnection(CachedConnectionManager.java:278) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:524) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:116) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:90) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:54) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2327) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:353) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:450) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:282) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:475) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:159) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:834) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:826) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.cascade(CascadingAction.java:357) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161) [:3.6.0.Final]
at
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some database connection is not explicitly closed. This may be due to improper Hibernate transaction configuration.

Since you are running on JBoss you must make sure Hibernate uses "JTA" and Hibernate can locate your XA dataSource:

```
hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/comp/env/jdbc/datasource
hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class =org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
```

If the problem persists then check [the following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252943/jboss-6-cachedconnectionmanager-closing-a-connection-for-you-please-close-th).

Comment: Sorry, can you please say me file to add these lines

Comment: this is persistence. xml?

Comment: I am injecting Data source using PersistenceContext. I am configuraing database in mysql-ds.xml

Comment: Yes, you can add them into persistence.xml.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252943/jboss-6-cachedconnectionmanager-closing-a-connection-for-you-please-close-th